# Most pythonic to call classes based on some value?

Tags: python

Lets say I have a list of animal names and i'd like to map them to specific objects like this.

```
class Dog(object)
   __init__(self,name,weight)
   def run()
   ...

class Cat(object)
   __init__(self,name,weight)
   def run()
```

...

map:

```
"baily" => Cat
"rocky" => Dog
"daisy" => Cat
```

What is the pythonic data structure I should use to creating this mapping? I want be able to do something like

```
animal = map['baily']('baily',33LB)
animal.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the most Pythonic way is to inherit them, however since you have strings we'll try to avoid that.

Why not use a dict?

```
class Dog(object):
    ...

class Cat(object):
    ...

class_mapping = {"baily":Cat, "rocky":Dog, "daisy":Cat}
animal = class_mapping["baily"]('baily', 33LB)
```

Another possibility is to build a function that knows the possible inputs (or otherwise can perform some introspection on them) to assign the correct class. For instance:

```
def Meta_Animal(name,*args,**kwargs):
    # I use class naming on this because it always produces a class
    if name.lower() in ['baily','daisy']:
        return Cat(name,*args, **kwargs)
    elif name.lower() in ['rocky']:
        return Dog(name,*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError("That name is not an animal")
```

Comment: That being said, although your question is very precise I'm confused as to WHY you want to do this. It seems like there would be a better way of doing whatever it is you want to do. Can you give me some background?

Comment: thats actually the first thing i thought of... but didn't think I could to map class name to dict...

Comment: @user3388884 classes in Python are a first order object. You can assign them as values of a dict (though likely not as keys, since you need a hashable object as a key)

Comment: I have several bs4 models (parsers) written and tested... now I have another script that generated a bunch of pages... some of the pages works with model1, others work with model2...etc so I want to map e.g. a.html, b.html, and c.html to model1, and e.html, g.html to model2... and so forth

Comment: @user3388884 I would implement a meta-class that can do some introspection on your page to see which parser it needs to use, then spawn its own instance of the parser to do so.

Comment: sorry, what is a meta class? is it just a general class that selects which model class to use? can u give me an simple example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57693/discussion-between-user3388884-and-adam-smith).